# Yii2 show error when exception occurs

Tags: exception, transactions, yii2, model-validation

I have this code in my controller:

```
...
if (Model::validateMultiple($ttepk)) {
    $transaction = \Yii::$app->db->beginTransaction();
    try {
        foreach ($ttepk as $ttep) {
            $ttep->save(false);
            if (!$ttep->assignPs()) {
                throw new UserException('assignPs failed');
            }
        }
        $transaction->commit();
        return $this->redirect(['index']);
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        $transaction->rollBack();
        throw $ex;
    }
}
...
```

in model:

```
...
public function assignPs() {
    foreach (...) {
        $ttepetk[...] = new Ttepet;
        $ttepetk[...]->ttepId = $this->id;
        ... // set other attributes
        }
    }

    if (Model::validateMultiple($ttepetk)) {
        foreach ($ttepetk as $ttepet) {
            $ttepet->save(false);
        }
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
...
```

Everything is working fine (no inserts are happening if any of the models fail validation), except that I would like to see the exact error, exactly by which Ttep (each Ttep is a model) and by which Ttepet (Ttep:Ttepet = 1:N) has the error happened, and what was that. Now I see the Exeption page only, and I don't know how to make the errors visible. Please point me to the right direction. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could iterate on each single model validating one by one and getting the errors when occurs  ...

```
if (Model::validateMultiple($ttepetk)) {
    foreach ($ttepetk as $ttepet) {
        $ttepet->save(false);
    }
    return true;
} else {
  foreach($ttepetk as $model){
      if ($model->validate()) {
        // all inputs are valid
    } else {
      // validation failed: $errors is an array containing error messages
      $errors = $model->errors;
    }
  }
    return $errors;  
}
```

you can get the errors this way

```
  $myErrorResult = $ttep->assignPs();
  if (!$myErrorResult) {
          ......
```

Comment: Okay, that's fine, but how to include transactions?

Comment: My attention was on the main function but your question have lead me to your controller code.. and you call a loadMultiple (validation) that  is already passed ..this way  how can throw the exception .. seems there are some issue with the logic.. so .. my answer is a suggestion for gettings errors like you asked  in title .. and i think you should reevealuate your controller code in a way that don't repeat several time the same validation..i hope this is useful for you ..

Comment: I think I don't repeat the same validation... but I'm going to try to implement your idea somehow and see what can I achieve. Thx!

Comment: the first is `Model::validateMultiple($ttepk)`, and the second is `Model::validateMultiple($ttepetk)` so corresponding models, and not the same.

Comment: For the transaction you can return the $errors from the  function assignPs and mange this result conforming to the Excecption you want throw

Comment: I hope this could be useful

Comment: I know it's a lame question, but how do I reach $errors in Controller...?

Comment: You can easly get the results form the function and then evaluate

Comment: Just like that? So simple? Awesome. Many thanks! I think I can go further now!

Comment: Can I ask one more small lame question? I get either 1 (true?) or an array back with errors. How is the nice way to handle it? Should I do: `if ($ttep->assignPs() <> 1) ...` ? That would look awkward to me. I'm sure there is a more sophisticated way.

Comment: In fact the nicest would be if I would return the objects with error and render the corresponding form of Model Ttepet. I'll give that a try.